# Traling Slash redirect for Prestashop Categories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can I use the Trailing Slash 301 redirect only (!) for Prestashop Categories?

I have this solution, but this forces for all URL´s.

```
#Force trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^/]*$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I have this rewrite for my URL´s.

```
Categories : {rewrite}/
Product: {category:/}{rewrite}.html
```

I need this for the 404 Error if I use some Category without slash:

```
http://shop.domain.com/category_example  -> 404 error
```

must redirect to

http://shop.domain.com/category_example/

Answer (score 0):

In backoffice go to `Preferences -> SEO & URLs` and set `Route to category` as `{id}-{rewrite:/}`.

This will use trailing slashes for categories and redirect categories without trailing slash to proper URL with slash.

Comment: Hello, this doesnt work, because the root category (index-php) became 404 error. My URL is also without ID it looks: {rewrite}/

Comment: @user3221012 How can you even set category and product routing without `{id}`? PrestaShop doesn't allow routing without it, at least not from backoffice settings. But if you're using some SEO module then you might wanna ask the developer about this.

Comment: Its working with Dispachter and Link.php override. This is important for Friendly URL for SEO Campaigns.

Comment: All my PS projects working with this friendly URL´s. Anyway i try now with htaccess redirect

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to your .htaccess file:

```
  # Various rewrite rules.
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #--------------- custom redirects -----------------
  #hard coded  
  RewriteRule ^this_is_hot_news/index\.html http://www.mysite/news [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule (.*)/index\.html$ http://www.mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ http://www.mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteRule (.*)/index\.php$ http://www.mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ http://www.mysite.nl/$1 [R=301,L]

  #end custom redirects
```